# Zip with default value instead of dropping values?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm looking for a function in haskell to zip two lists that may vary in length.
All zip functions I could find just drop all values of a lists that is longer than the other.

For example:
In my exercise I have two example lists.
If the first one is shorter than the second one I have to fill up using 0's. Otherwise I have to use 1's.
I'm not allowed to use any recursion. I just have to use higher order functions.

Is there any function I can use?
I really could not find any solution so far.

Comment: a duplicate Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403029/how-to-zip-lists-with-different-length.

Comment: @WillNess rather your referenced question is a duplicate as mine is older

Comment: yes, that is the intention.

Comment: @WillNess ah ok sry then i got you wrong :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can append an inifinte list of 0 or 1 to each list and then take the number you need from the result zipped list:

```
zipWithDefault :: a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipWithDefault da db la lb = let len = max (length la) (length lb)
                                 la' = la ++ (repeat da)
                                 lb' = lb ++ (repeat db)
                             in take len $ zip la' lb'
```

Comment: @Lee: Sorry, my bad, it does. It breaks on infinite lists though (even if one is infinite), but that's already been mentioned. My answer below works with infinite and finite lists.

Answer (score 43):

There is some structure to this problem, and here it comes. I'll be using this stuff:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable
import Data.List
```

First up, lists-with-padding are a useful concept, so let's have a type for them.

```
data Padme m = (:-) {padded :: [m], padder :: m} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Next, I remember that the truncating-`zip` operation gives rise to an `Applicative` instance, in the library as `newtype ZipList` (a popular example of a non-`Monad`). The `Applicative ZipList` amounts to a decoration of the monoid given by infinity and minimum. `Padme` has a similar structure, except that its underlying monoid is positive numbers (with infinity), using one and maximum.

```
instance Applicative Padme where
  pure = ([] :-)
  (fs :- f) <*> (ss :- s) = zapp fs ss :- f s where
    zapp  []        ss        = map f ss
    zapp  fs        []        = map ($ s) fs
    zapp  (f : fs)  (s : ss)  = f s : zapp fs ss
```

I am obliged to utter the usual incantation to generate a default `Functor` instance.

```
instance Functor Padme where fmap = (<*>) . pure
```

Thus equipped, we can pad away! For example, the function which takes a ragged list of strings and pads them with spaces becomes a one liner.

```
deggar :: [String] -> [String]
deggar = transpose . padded . traverse (:- ' ')
```

See?

```
*Padme> deggar ["om", "mane", "padme", "hum"]
["om   ","mane ","padme","hum  "]
```

Comment: This data structure feels wrong to me. The padding value should be at the end of the list, where it's used, not side-by-side with the head. Something like `data Listttt a = Repeat a | Cons a (Listttt a)`.

Comment: @benrg Arranging it like that would impose a linear cost in accessing the padder, in case you ever need to use it for something else.

Answer (score 11):

This can be expressed using [`These`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.4/docs/Data-These.html#t:These) ("represents values with two non-exclusive possibilities") and [`Align`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.4/docs/Data-Align.html#Align) ("functors supporting a zip operation that takes the union of non-uniform shapes") from the *these* library:

```
import Data.Align
import Data.These

zipWithDefault :: Align f => a -> b -> f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
zipWithDefault da db = alignWith (fromThese da db)
```

[`salign`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.4/docs/Data-Align.html#v:salign) and the other specialised aligns in `Data.Align` are also worth having a look at.

<sub>Thanks to u/WarDaft, u/gallais and u/sjakobi over at r/haskell for pointing out this answer should exist here.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

myZip dx dy xl yl = 
  map (\(x,y) -> (fromMaybe dx x, fromMaybe dy y)) $ 
    takeWhile (/= (Nothing, Nothing)) $ 
    zip ((map Just xl) ++ (repeat Nothing)) ((map Just yl) ++ (repeat Nothing))

main = print $ myZip 0 1 [1..10] [42,43,44]
```

Basically, append an infinite list of `Nothing` to the end of both lists, then zip them, and drop the results when both are `Nothing`. Then replace the `Nothing`s with the appropriate default value, dropping the no longer needed `Just`s while you're at it.

Answer (score 4):

No `length`, no counting, no hand-crafted recursions, no cooperating folds. `transpose` does the trick:

```
zipLongest :: a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipLongest x y xs ys = map head . transpose $   -- longest length;
                [                                 --   view from above:
                  zip  xs 
                      (ys ++ repeat y)            -- with length of xs
                , zip (xs ++ repeat x) 
                       ys                         -- with length of ys
                ]
```

The result of `transpose` is as long a list as the longest one in its input list of lists. `map head` takes the first element in each "column", which is the pair we need, whichever the longest list was.

---

*(update:)* For an *arbitrary* number of lists, efficient padding to the maximal length -- aiming to avoid the potentially quadratic behaviour of other *sequentially*-combining approaches -- can follow the same idea:

```
padAll :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
padAll x xss = transpose $ 
   zipWith const
      (transpose [xs ++ repeat x | xs <- xss])         -- pad all, and cut
      (takeWhile id . map or . transpose $             --   to the longest list
         [ (True <$ xs) ++ repeat False | xs <- xss])

> mapM_ print $ padAll '-' ["ommmmmmm", "ommmmmm", "ommmmm", "ommmm", "ommm",
   "omm", "om", "o"]
"ommmmmmm"
"ommmmmm-"
"ommmmm--"
"ommmm---"
"ommm----"
"omm-----"
"om------"
"o-------"
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to compare list lengths. Try to think about your zip function as a function taking only one argument `xs` and returning a *function* which will take `ys` and perform the required zip. Then, try to write a *recursive* function which recurses on `xs` only, as follows.

```
type Result = [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
myZip :: [Int] -> Result
myZip []     = map (\y -> (0,y)) -- :: Result
myZip (x:xs) = f x (myZip xs)    -- :: Result
   where f x k = ???             -- :: Result
```

Once you have found f, notice that you can turn the recursion above into a fold!

Answer (score 2):

As you said yourself, the standard `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` drops elements from the longer list. To amend for this fact you can modify your input *before* giving it to `zip`. First you will have to find out which list is the shorter one (most likely, using `length`). E.g.,

```hs
zip' x xs y ys | length xs <= length ys  =  ...
               | otherwise               =  ...
```

where `x` is the default value for shorter `xs` and `y` the default value for shorter `ys`.

Then you extend the shorter list with the desired default elements (enough to account for the additional elements of the other list). A neat trick for doing so without having to know the length of the longer list is to use the function `repeat :: a -> [a]` that repeats its argument infinitely often.

```hs
zip' x xs y ys | length xs <= length ys = zip {-do something with xs-} ys
               | otherwise              = zip xs {-do something with ys-}
```

Comment: @augustss: Right. I should have mentioned it in my post.

Comment: Also quite inefficient.

Comment: if memory serves, the augustss's deleted comment was "doesn't work with infinite lists". `length` is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, that does work on infinite lists and is a straightforward upgrade of Prelude's zip functions:

```
zipDefault :: a ->  b -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipDefault _da _db []     []     = []
zipDefault  da  db (a:as) []     = (a,db) : zipDefault da db as []
zipDefault  da  db []     (b:bs) = (da,b) : zipDefault da db [] bs
zipDefault  da  db (a:as) (b:bs) = (a,b)  : zipDefault da db as bs
```

and

```
zipDefaultWith :: a -> b -> (a->b->c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipDefaultWith _da _db _f []     []     = []
zipDefaultWith  da  db  f (a:as) []     = f  a db : zipDefaultWith da db f as []
zipDefaultWith  da  db  f []     (b:bs) = f da  b : zipDefaultWith da db f [] bs
zipDefaultWith  da  db  f (a:as) (b:bs) = f  a  b : zipDefaultWith da db f as bs
```

@pigworker, thank you for your enlightening solution!

Answer (score 2):

Yet another implementation:

```
zipWithDefault :: a -> b -> (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithDefault dx _  f []     ys     = zipWith f (repeat dx) ys
zipWithDefault _  dy f xs     []     = zipWith f xs (repeat dy)
zipWithDefault dx dy f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWithDefault dx dy f xs ys
```

And also:

```
zipDefault :: a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipDefault dx dy = zipWithDefault dx dy (,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to address the second part of Will Ness's solution, with its excellent use of known functions, by providing another to the original question.

```
zipPadWith :: a -> b -> (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipPadWith n _ f [] l          = [f n x | x <- l]
zipPadWith _ m f l []          = [f x m | x <- l]
zipPadWith n m f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipPadWith n m f xs ys
```

This function will pad a list with an element of choice. You can use a list of the same element repeated as many times as the number of lists in another like this:

```
rectangularWith :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
rectangularWith _ []       = []
rectangularWith _ [ms]     = [[m] | m <- ms]
rectangularWith n (ms:mss) = zipPadWith n [n | _ <- mss] (:) ms (rectangularWith n mss)
```

The end result will have been a transposed rectangular list of lists padded by the element that we provided so we only need to import `transpose` from `Data.List` and recover the order of the elements.

```
mapM_ print $ transpose $ rectangularWith 0 [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9]]

[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,0,0]
[7,8,0,0]
[9,0,0,0]
```