# How to zip lists with different length?

Tags: haskell

How can I `zip` two lists like

```
["Line1","Line2","Line3"]
["Line4","Line5"]
```

without discarding rest elements in first list?

I'd like to zip extra elements with empty list, if it can be done.

Comment: Well, if you don't discard them, what else do you do? Pad the shorter list? If so, with what value(s)?

Comment: I edit my question. It'll be good, if after that `zip` there will be elements like `("string",[])`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349408/zip-with-default-value-instead-of-dropping-values

Comment: `zip list_a $ list_b ++ repeat ""`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
zipWithPadding :: a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipWithPadding a b (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : zipWithPadding a b xs ys
zipWithPadding a _ []     ys     = zip (repeat a) ys
zipWithPadding _ b xs     []     = zip xs (repeat b)
```

As long as there are elements, we can simply zip them. As soon as we run out of elements, we simply zip the remaining list with an infinite list of the padding element.

In your case, you would use this as

```
zipWithPadding "" "" ["Line1","Line2","Line3"] ["Line4","Line5"]
-- result: [("Line1","Line4"),("Line2","Line5"),("Line3","")]
```

Comment: Note to those who want to see `mempty` or `Monoid`: `zipWithPadding mempty mempty` will give you your `(Monoid a, Monoid b) => [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is to make a zip function that works on monoids and fills in the missing values with mempty:

```
import Data.Monoid

mzip :: (Monoid a, Monoid b) => [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
mzip (a:as) (b:bs) = (a, b) : mzip as bs
mzip []     (b:bs) = (mempty, b) : mzip [] bs
mzip (a:as) []     = (a, mempty) : mzip as []
mzip _      _      = []

> mzip ["Line1","Line2","Line3"] ["Line4","Line5"]
[("Line1","Line4"),("Line2","Line5"),("Line3","")]
```

Comment: @Riccardo I wouldn't say that it's way better, the accepted answer will work in situations when you don't necessarily have a `Monoid`, and may want to use different defaults for different zips.  The data might not have a good meaning for `<>`, but would still have a sane `mempty` (or multiple sane defaults).  Best practice in Haskell says to use the least restrictive type possible, using `Monoid` restricts this function more than necessary since `<>` is not used.  Besides, `mzip` can be defined in terms of `zipWithPadding` by just passing `mempty` to both defaults.

Comment: @Riccardo I personally think it would be useful if the standard libraries defined a `class Default m where mempty :: m` and `class Default m => Monoid m where mappend :: m -> m -> m`.

Comment: @Riccardo: `mzip = zipWithPadding mempty mempty`. Just because something uses `Monoid` doesn't make it better or more powerful ;).

Comment: I see my comment was definitely too short not to be misunderstood, let me clarify :)
I agree on the fact that the `zipWithPadding` solution is more general, no doubt about that. But the question was specifically about lists of strings, as the OP explicitly asks for a padding with `""`. In this regard, a solution involving monoids is not only imho general enough with respect to the OP, but also simpler than having to specify two default arguments which will not change. That's why I like the `mempty` solution the most.

Comment: @Riccardo I agree that for the particular problem, the `Monoid` based solution is particularly applicable, maybe even desirable.  I've actually given a vote to both this solution and Zeta's above, I think they're both great solutions.  The distinction I wanted to make was that a `Monoid` is not always necessary to solve a problem in which you need a default value, so that doesn't mean that the monoidal solution is any better than the more general form, just an alternative that imposes a few additional restrictions which many not be easy to work around.

Comment: It looks like someone has already implemented a `Default` class in the `data-default`.  You could instead write `mzip` with the signature `(Default a, Default b) => [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` and replace `mempty` with `def`.  It already has numerous instances for common types, so it would be my choice in this situation if I were already dependent on that package.

Comment: Why Monoids instead of MonadPlus (using mzero) ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative implementation of Reite's solution, using higher order functions, just for fun. :) Possibly slower, though, since I guess the length functions will require additional traversals of the lists.

```
import Data.Monoid (mempty)

zipPad :: (Monoid a, Monoid b) => [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipPad xs ys = take maxLength $ zip (pad xs) (pad ys)
    where
        maxLength = max (length xs) (length ys)
        pad v = v ++ repeat mempty
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be much simple for you if you are new one in programming in Haskell

```
         zip' :: [String] -> [String] ->[(String,String)]
         zip' [][] = []
         zip' (x:xs)[] = bmi x : zip' xs []
                   where bmi x = (x,"")
         zip' [](x:xs) = bmi x : zip' [] xs
                   where bmi x = ("",x)
         zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = bmi x y : zip' xs ys
                   where bmi x y = (x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I don't want to pad my list. For instance, when I want to zip equal length lists only. Here is a general purpose solution, which maybe returns any extra values if one list is longer.

```
zipWithSave :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> ([c],Maybe (Either [a] [b]))
zipWithSave f    []     []  = ([],Nothing)
zipWithSave f    []     bs  = ([],Just (Right bs))
zipWithSave f    as     []  = ([],Just (Left as))
zipWithSave f (a:as) (b:bs) = (f a b : cs , sv)
  where (cs, sv) = zipWithSave f as bs
```

Using `(zps,svs) = zipWithSave f as bs`, `svs` can be one of three cases: `Just (Left x)` wherein leftovers from `as` are returned as `x`, `Just (Right x)` wherein leftovers from `bs` are returned, or `Nothing` in the case of equal length lists.

Another general purpose one is to just supply extra functions for each case.

```
zipWithOr :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithOr _ _  _     []    []   = []
zipWithOr _ _  fb    []     bs  = map fb bs
zipWithOr _ fa _     as     []  = map fa as
zipWithOr f fa fb (a:as) (b:bs) = (f a b) : zipWithOr f fa fb as bs
```

This is just an elaboration of Zeta's approach. That function is then implemented as (using {-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}):

```
zipWithPadding a b as bs = zipWithOr (,) (,b) (a,) as bs
```