# sum3 with zipWith3 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a Haskell function that would take three lists and return a list of sums of their elements.
Currently I'm trying to do it using zipWith3:

```
sum3 :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sum3 xs ys zs  = zipWith3 (\x y z -> x+y+z) xs ys zs
```

The problem is it only works for lists of equal lengths. But I wish `sum3` to work with lists of unequal lengths, so that

```
sum3 [1,2,3] [4,5] [6]
```

would return

```
[11,7,3]
```

I think that I should redefine zipWith3 to work with lists of unequal lengths, but can't figure out how to do it (I suspect that I have to exhaust all possibilities of empty lists).
Is there a solution?

Comment: You will have to pass an additional argument, the default value to use when some of the lists are exhausted.

Comment: usually that value is `0` when you sum up I think

Comment: btw: you could extent the solution here if you just concat `repeat 0` to the smaller lists - but IMO this is to ugly to propose ;)

Comment: @Carsten but how should zipWith know whether you are summing up or doing something else?

Comment: Actually, I suspect that there's a solution that should work with any function normal `zipWith3` works with, not just addition.

Comment: Add `a` to the beginning of every element, resulting in `[ab,ac,ad]`

Comment: Let's talk `zipWith` for simplicity (no 3). What should `zipWith (:) "a" ["b", "c"]` do?

Comment: Sorry edited for correctness. But that's not what you specified for your sum function. It doesn't add the last element from the exhausted list, it adds zero. Please try to specify your desired result formally for generic arguments. Again start with the two-list version for simplicity.

Answer (score 12):

a nice trick is to use [`transpose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose):

```
import Data.List (transpose)

sum3 :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sum3 as bs cs = map sum $ transpose [as,bs,cs]
```

because obviously you want to sum up the *columns* ;)

---

```
> sum3 [1,2,3] [4,5] [6]
[11,7,3]
```

Comment: Quite nice, thanks! Still, it's interesting to implement it with `zipWith3`

Answer (score 6):

I've seen this sort of question before, here: [Zip with default value instead of dropping values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21349408/828361) [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21350096/828361) to that question also pertains here.

The `ZipList` applicative 
Lists with a designated padding element are applicative (the applicative grown from the 1 and max monoid structure on positive numbers).

```
data Padme m = (:-) {padded :: [m], padder :: m} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Applicative Padme where
  pure = ([] :-)
  (fs :- f) <*> (ss :- s) = zapp fs ss :- f s where
    zapp  []        ss        = map f ss
    zapp  fs        []        = map ($ s) fs
    zapp  (f : fs)  (s : ss)  = f s : zapp fs ss

-- and for those of you who don't have DefaultSuperclassInstances
instance Functor Padme where fmap = (<*>) . pure
```

Now we can pack up lists of numbers with their appropriate padding

```
pad0 :: [Int] -> Padme Int
pad0 = (:- 0)
```

And that gives

```
padded ((\x y z -> x+y+z) <$> pad0 [1,2,3] <*> pad0 [4,5] <*> pad0 [6])
= [11,7,3]
```

Or, with the Idiom Brackets that aren't available, you vould write

```
padded (|pad0 [1,2,3] + (|pad0 [4,5] + pad0 6|)|)
```

meaning the same.

`Applicative` gives you a good way to bottle the essential idea of "padding" that this problem demands.

Comment: Is there a reason we can't simply write `(|pad0 [1,2,3] + pad0 [4,5] + pad0 [6]|)` (you missed the `[]` around `6`, BTW)? Or, more generally, can we treat `(...)` inside `(|...|)` as `(|...|)`?

Comment: definitely not the answer the OP's looking for but a good advanced applicative tutorial nevertheless!

Comment: @user3237465 It's a moot point. The short, bad answer is that I never got around to adding precedence/associaitivity handling to the SHE parser. The better answer is that idiom brackets give you one top level application. But arguably, they should apply for a whole code region, provided there is a clear way to signal which subtrees have gone back to "normal".

Answer (score 2):

Well if you *must* use `zipWith3`:

```
sum3 :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sum3 xs ys zs = zipWith3 (\x y z -> x + y + z) xs' ys' zs'
  where
    xs' = pad nx xs;  nx = length xs
    ys' = pad ny ys;  ny = length ys
    zs' = pad nz zs;  nz = length zs
    n   = nx `max` ny `max` nz
    pad n' = (++ replicate (n-n') 0)
```

Some samples:

```
*> sum3 [] [] []
[]
*> sum3 [0] [] []
[0]
*> sum3 [1] [1] [2, 2]
[4,2]
*> sum3 [1,2,3] [4,5] [6]
[11,7,3]
```

but I'd recommend going with Carsten's `transpose` based implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could get away with something that is *almost* `zipWith3` but which relies on `Default` to generate empty values on the fly if one of the lists runs out of elements:

```hs
import Data.Default

zipWith3' :: (Default a, Default b, Default c)
          => ( a  ->  b  ->  c  ->  r )
          -> ([a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [r])
zipWith3' f = go where
  go  []     []     []    =           []
  go (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = f x y z : go xs    ys    zs
  go  []     ys     zs    =           go [def] ys    zs
  go  xs     []     zs    =           go xs    [def] zs
  go  xs     ys     []    =           go xs    ys    [def]
```

and 'sum3'`:

```hs
sum3' :: (Default a, Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sum3' = zipWith3' (\x y z -> x + y + z)
```

Answer (score 2):

One could generalize `zipWith` so to handle the excess tails, instead of discarding them silently.

```
zipWithK :: (a->b->c) -> ([a]->[c]) -> ([b]->[c]) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithK fab fa fb = go
  where go [] [] = []
        go as [] = fa as
        go [] bs = fb bs
        go (a:as) (b:bs) = fab a b : go as bs
```

The original `zipWith` is then

```
zipWith' :: (a->b->c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f = zipWithK f (const []) (const [])
```

Back to the original problem,

```
sum2 :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sum2 = zipWithK (+) id id

sum3 :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sum3 xs ys zs  = xs `sum2` ys `sum2` zs
```

Comment: The previous answer seems correct, but this one is more general. Which should be accepted as the correct one?

Comment: Whichever you prefer! it doesn't matter at all in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
sumLists :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sumLists (x : xs) (y : ys) = (x + y) : sumLists xs ys
sumLists _ _ = []

sum3 :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sum3 xs ys zs = foldr sumLists defaultList (map addElems list)
  where list = [xs, ys, zs]
        defaultList = [] ++ [0, 0 ..]
        maxLength = maximum $ map length list
        addElems = \x -> if length x < maxLength then x ++ [0, 0 ..] else x
```