# Ziplists with longest-style applicative behaviour

Tags: haskell, applicative

Is it possible in Haskell do define a type similar to ziplist, in which operation `a <*> b` will produce list which is as long as the *longest* of `a` and `b`.

It is clear that in this case we must assume that `a` and `b` are lists over something like Monoid, so tentative declaration is:

```
   instance Monoid a => Applicative (ZList a) where ...
```

which clearly will not typecheck. Another tentative approach is to use GADTs with constrained constructors, something like

```
   data ZList a where 
     Z:: ZList a
     S:: Monoid a => a-> (ZList a) -> (ZList a)
```

but then I stuck on a stage of making it Functor because we cannot guarantee that in `fmap::(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, b will be Monoid.

Clearly, this question extends to wider class of algebraic datatypes for which we want to define "pointwise" applicative behavior in which we produce output with shape similar to the *union* of shapes of the arguments.

Comment: do you have some computation in mind which will benefit from this? There is [`Data.Align`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.2/docs/Data-Align.html) which is container-oriented (and not computaton/context), which might be what you are looking for?

Comment: Defining such a type is far from your biggest issue (you can define `Functor` for any type with the [left Kan extension](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Kan-Lan.html)). You must decide on a semantics which is consistent with the Applicative laws - for example, what is `pure`? `pure id <*> a` must equal `a` - so `pure` would have to take as a parameter something indicating the length of the list to which it will be applied in the future - otherwise you cannot produce a list of precisely `length a` from `pure`.

Comment: The definition of the typeclass that will allow this is known as the [Constrained Typeclass Problem](http://ku-fpg.github.io/practice/constrainedTypeClassInstances/), and there have been a few approaches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zip with default value instead of dropping values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349408/zip-with-default-value-instead-of-dropping-values)

Answer (score 2):

First, what you really want is probably [`Default`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-0.7.1.1/docs/Data-Default.html#t:Default), not `Monoid` - you have no use for `mappend`.

I don't think anything useful is possible in `Applicative` itself. That said, I can define a version of `(<*>)` (called `(<#>)`) with extra constraints that lets me do what I think you have in mind.

### Why there is no point in making a new data type

First, suppose we *were* to take the `ExistentialQuantification` route in hopes of pushing our constraints into the `data` and having legitimate instances of `Functor` and `Applicative`.  That blows up as soon as we try to define `fmap`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data ZipMonList a = Default a => ZipMonList [a]

-- Woops, we still need a constraint for `Default b`
fmap :: Default b => (a -> b) -> ZipMonList a -> ZipMonList b
fmap f (ZipMonList xs) = ZipMonList (f xs)
```

So, with that settled, let's stick to the `ZipList` type (since we want the same `(<$>)` anyways) and just define our new constrained version of `(<*>)`, called `(<#>)`.

### Make `(<#>)` for `ZipList`

Underlying `ZipList`s `(<*>)` is the `zipWith` function. We need something similar for `(<#>)`, but that extends lists. Then, `(<#>)` looks a lot like `(<*>)`:

```
import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..))
import Data.Default

-- Like 'zipWith', but has maximum length
zipWith' :: (Default a, Default b) => (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f []     []     = []
zipWith' f (x:xs) []     = f x   def : zipWith' f xs []
zipWith' f []     (y:ys) = f def y   : zipWith' f [] ys
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x   y   : zipWith' f xs ys

-- same fixity as <*>
infixl 4 <#> 

-- like '(<*>)', but uses 'zipWith'' instead of 'zipWith'
(<#>) :: (Default a, Default b) => ZipList (a -> b) -> ZipList a -> ZipList b
ZipList fs <#> ZipList xs = ZipList (zipWith' id fs xs)
```

And I can do a test run on tuples:

```
ghci> (,,) <$> ZipList [1.2,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.1] <#> ZipList [[(),()],[()],[(),(),()]] <#> ZipList [1,2,3,4]
ZipList {getZipList = [(1.2,[(),()],1),(3.4,[()],2),(5.6,[(),(),()],3),(7.8,[],4),(9.1,[],0)]}
```

Key takeaway point: this is *not* an `Applicative`, but still doable.

Comment: This doesn't actually work as we would probably like.  Consider `(*) <$> ZipList [1,1,1] <#> ZipList [4]` which evaluates to `ZipList [4,0,0]`, when it seems like it should be `ZipList [4,1,1]`.

Comment: @luqui Isn't that a problem inherent in trying to solve this in the applicative "format"? Your assumption that you should get back `ZipList [4,1,1]` implies something about the fact `(*)` forms a monoid with identity `1`, which is much more information than we get in the `(<#>)` operator.

Comment: yes I think it probably is.  I'm trying to give a satisfying explanation now, but I might abort the task :-P

Answer (score 1):

I just have a few notes for you, things to think about.

The definition of the typeclass that will allow this is known as the [Constrained Typeclass Problem](http://ku-fpg.github.io/practice/constrainedTypeClassInstances/), and there have been a few approaches.

I notice that you have only specified that the resulting list should be as long as the longer of the two lists, but you haven't said what the remaining elements should be.  At that point you might as well use the applicative

```
ZipList :*: Const (MaxPos Int)
```

(where [`:*:` is functor product](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.12/docs/Control-Compose.html#t::-42-:), and `MaxPos` is a monoid I just made up taking the maximum on nonnegative numbers) which keeps track of the "length" separately, because the remaining elements will be meaningless.

Rather, I suspect you mean something where the remaining elements are preserved in some sense, i.e. so

```
(*) <$> [2,3,4] <*> [4] = [8,3,4]
```

and also

```
(+) <$> [2,3,4] <*> [4] = [6,3,4]
```

So if we were to "fill in" missing elements in the former case we should fill them in with 1, and in the latter we should fill them in with 0.  This starts to show us a different aspect of the problem; we need to pick identity elements based on the operation, or just "leave alone" the remaining elements (which constrains the operations to type `a -> a -> a`).  This is looking less possible, it'd be interesting to explore more.  That's all I've got for now, sorry.