# Haskell: Merging a list where even indices are from list 1 and odd are from list 2. Fill with 0's if not the same size

Tags: list, haskell, zero-padding

i've tried to create a Haskell function that is merging 2 lists into a single list, where even indices in the new list are from list 1 and the odd are from list 2. Fill with 0's if not the same size.

For example:

```
[1] [10,15,20] => [1,10,0,15,0,20] 
[2,3] [4,5] => [2,4,3,5]
```

I've tried to create a couple of versions but with no luck.

How can I create such a thing?

Comment: Look at the implementation of `zip` at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `interleave` function, that does something similar, however, not exactly that. It 'merges' lists until one of them ends.

So you can write that function by yourself:

```
merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys
merge (x:xs) [] = x : 0 : merge xs []
merge [] (y:ys) = 0 : y : merge [] ys
merge _ _ = []
```

When we have some elements on both sides, we take both of them. When one of elements is absent, we take 0 instead of it. In all other cases (it is the `merge [] []` case) we end up with our recursion and return an empty list.

We can also slightly generalize our function to support any number-like type:

```
merge :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys
merge (x:xs) [] = x : 0 : merge xs []
merge [] (y:ys) = 0 : y : merge [] ys
merge _ _ = []
```

Also, we can go further and use `def` from [Data.Default](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) package to get the default value for our type, so we can use this function with not only lists of numbers:

```
import Data.Default

merge :: Default a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys
merge (x:xs) [] = x : def : merge xs []
merge [] (y:ys) = def : y : merge [] ys
merge _ _ = []
```

Comment: That answers it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970785/849891) of mine, using the [`transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) function,

```
interweaveWith :: a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interweaveWith def xs ys =
   -- 0 [1] [10,15,20] => [1,10,0,15,0,20] 
   concat $
      zipWith const
         (transpose [ xs ++ repeat def,      -- no limit, padded with def
                      ys ++ repeat def ])
         (transpose [xs, ys])                -- as long as the longest
```