# Sum corresponding elements of two lists, with the extra elements of the longer list added at the end

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to add two lists together and keep the extra elements that are unused and add those into the new list e.g.

- `addLists [1,2,3] [1,3,5,7,9] = [2,5,8,7,9]`

I have this so far:

```
addLists :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addLists xs ys = zipWith (+) xs ys
```

but unsure of how to get the extra elements into the new list.

and the next step is changing this to a higher order function that takes the combining function
as an argument:

```
longZip :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Take a look at how `zipWith` is implemented, and use explicit recursion.

Comment: im stuck on how to write the explicit recursion part @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zipWith):

> ```
> zipWith :: (a->b->c) -> [a]->[b]->[c]
> zipWith f = go
>   where
>     go [] _ = []
>     go _ [] = []
>     go (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go xs ys
> ```

It thus uses explicit recursion where `go` will check if the two lists are non-empty and in that case yield `f x y`, otherwise it stops and returns an empty list `[]`.

You can implement a variant of `zipWith` which will continue, even if one of the lists is empty. THis will look like:

```
zipLongest :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipLongest f = go
  where go [] ys = …
        go xs [] = …
        go (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go xs ys
```

where you still need to fill in `…`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with higher order functions as simple as

```
import Data.List (transpose)

addLists :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addLists xs ys = map sum . transpose $ [xs, ys]
```

because the length of [`transpose`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=transpose)`[xs, ys, ...]` is the length of the longest list in its argument list, and [`sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=sum) is already defined to sum the elements of a list (since lists are `Foldable`).

`transpose` is used here as a kind of a `zip` (but cutting on the longest instead of the shortest list), with `[]` being a default element for the lists addition `++`, like `0` is a default element for the numbers addition `+`:

```
cutLongest [xs, ys] $
  zipWith (++) (map pure xs ++ repeat []) (map pure ys ++ repeat [])
```

See also:

- [Zip with default value instead of dropping values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349408/zip-with-default-value-instead-of-dropping-values)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [the `semialign` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semialign-1.1.0.1). It gives you an operation like zipping, but that keeps going until both lists run out. It also generalizes to types other than lists, such as [rose trees](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Tree.html#t:Tree). In your case, you'd use it like this:

```hs
import Data.Semialign
import Data.These

addLists :: (Semialign f, Num a) => f a -> f a -> f a
addLists = alignWith (mergeThese (+))

longZip :: Semialign f => (a -> a -> a) -> f a -> f a -> f a
longZip = alignWith . mergeThese
```

The new type signatures are optional. If you want, you can keep using your old ones that restrict them to lists.